# Python File seek + write output weird "NUL" in the file

Tags: python

I'm writting a downloader that will split url to parts and download with threading, probably I will not use "join" because join = unable to stream (cannot write file if all thread is not finish)

But problem is f.seek and write output really weird file, content of the file always have  "NUL" character (in Notepad++) and text in the file is just 1/3 of the whole file.

He everybody, thank everybody for helping me, here is my version 2.0 of the code, thank Padraic Cunningham for his suggestion and exlaination, I fix my code almost like what you've suggested:
So please help me check the code, and I think need you guy help to convert it to http.server file streamming method:

```
import os, requests
import threading
import urllib3
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import time
import re

pool = urllib3.PoolManager(maxsize=10)
URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/langpavel/tampermonkey/master/src/emulation.js"
fileName = "1.js"
countsize = 0
#if os.path.exists(fileName):
 #   os.remove(fileName)

def defwrite(filename,data,offset):
  f = open(filename,'wb')
  f.seek(offset)
  f.write(data)
  f.close()

def buildRange(url, numsplits):
    global pool
    value = int(requests.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}).headers.get('content-length', None))
    print("Fullsize: ", value)
    print("Try devide with 3 :", value / 3)
    lst = []
    for i in range(numsplits):
        if i == range(numsplits):
            lst.append('%s-%s' % (i * value//numsplits + 1, i * value//numsplits + 1 + (value - (i * value//numsplits + 1))))
        if i == 0:
            lst.append('%s-%s' % (0, value//numsplits))
        else:
            lst.append('%s-%s' % (i * value//numsplits + 1, (i + 1) * value//numsplits))
    return lst

def main(url=None, splitBy=3):
    global fileName, pool, countsize
    start_time = time.time()
    if not url:
        print("Please Enter some url to begin download.")
        return

    #fileName = "1.jpg"

    #print("%s bytes to download." % sizeInBytes)
   # if not sizeInBytes:
    #    print("Size cannot be determined.")
     #   return
    #sinzeInBytes = buildRange(url, 
    dataDict = {}
    f = open(fileName,'wb')

    # split total num bytes into ranges
    #ranges = buildRange(url,int(sizeInBytes), splitBy)
    ranges = buildRange(url, splitBy)
    print(ranges)
    def downloadChunk(idx, irange):
        print(idx)
        #time.sleep(1*idx)
        #req = urllib.request.Request(url)
        #req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes={}'.format(irange)
        headers = urllib3._collections.HTTPHeaderDict()
        headers.add('Range', 'bytes=' + str(irange))
        data = pool.urlopen('GET', URL, headers=headers).data
        #print(data)
        #print("finish: " + str(irange))
        offset = int(re.sub("(^.*?)-(.*?)$", "\\1", irange))
        print(offset)
       # print(irange)
        f.seek(offset, 0)
        #f.truncate(0)
        #print(f.tell())
        f.write(data)
        #f.read()
        #f.close()
        countsize = countsize + offset


        #defwrite("1.txt", req, re.sub("(^.*?)-", "\\1", str(irange)))

    # create one downloading thread per chunk
    downloaders = [
        threading.Thread(
            target=downloadChunk,
            args=(idx, irange),
        )
        for idx,irange in enumerate(ranges)
        ]


    # start threads, let run in parallel, wait for all to finish
    for th in downloaders:
        th.start()
        #th.isAlive()
    #for th in downloaders:
        #th.join()
        #print(th.join)
    print(countsize)
    #print('done: got {} chunks, total {} bytes'.format(
    #    len(dataDict), sum( (
    ##        len(chunk) for chunk in list(dataDict.values())
     #   ) )
    #))

    #print("--- %s seconds ---" % str(time.time() - start_time))

#    if os.path.exists(fileName):
 #       os.remove(fileName)
     #reassemble file in correct order
    #with open(fileName, 'wb') as fh:
    #    for _idx,chunk in sorted(dataDict.items()):
    #        fh.write(chunk)
    #stream_chunk = 16 * 1024
    #with open(fileName, 'wb') as fp:
    #  while True:
    #      for _idx,chunk in sorted(dataDict.items()):
            #fh.write(chunk)
     #       chunking = chunk.read(stream_chunk)
      #      if not chunk:
       #         break
        #    fp.write(chunking)


   # print("Finished Writing file %s" % fileName)
    #print('file size {} bytes'.format(os.path.getsize(fileName)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   if os.path.exists(fileName):
     os.remove(fileName)
   main(URL, splitBy=16)
```

Here is my code, please help me fix it: Version 1.0, ignore it, version 2.0 above:

```
import os, requests
import threading
import urllib3
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import time
import re

pool = urllib3.PoolManager(maxsize=10)
URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/langpavel/tampermonkey/master/src/emulation.js"
fileName = "1.js"
#if os.path.exists(fileName):
 #   os.remove(fileName)

def defwrite(filename,data,offset):
  f = open(filename,'wb')
  f.seek(offset)
  f.write(data)
  f.close()

def buildRange(value, numsplits):
    lst = []
    for i in range(numsplits):
        if i == range(numsplits):
            lst.append('%s-%s' % (int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0),0)), int(value - round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0) + value/(numsplits*1.0)-1, 0))))
        if i == 0:
            lst.append('%s-%s' % (i, int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0) + value/(numsplits*1.0)-1, 0))))
        else:
            lst.append('%s-%s' % (int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0),0)), int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0) + value/(numsplits*1.0)-1, 0))))
    return lst

def main(url=None, splitBy=3):
    global fileName, pool
    start_time = time.time()
    if not url:
        print("Please Enter some url to begin download.")
        return

    #fileName = "1.jpg"
    sizeInBytes = requests.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}).headers.get('content-length', None)
    print("%s bytes to download." % sizeInBytes)
    if not sizeInBytes:
        print("Size cannot be determined.")
        return

    dataDict = {}

    # split total num bytes into ranges
    ranges = buildRange(int(sizeInBytes), splitBy)

    def downloadChunk(idx, irange):
        print(idx)
        #req = urllib.request.Request(url)
        #req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes={}'.format(irange)
        headers = urllib3._collections.HTTPHeaderDict()
        headers.add('Range', 'bytes=' + str(irange))
        data = pool.urlopen('GET', URL, headers=headers).data
        print(data)
        print("finish: " + str(irange))
        offset = int(re.sub("(^.*?)-(.*?)$", "\\1", irange))
        #print(offset)
       # print(irange)
        f = open(fileName,'wb')
        f.seek(offset)
        #f.truncate(0)
        #print(f.tell())
        f.write(data)
        #f.read()
        #f.close()



        #defwrite("1.txt", req, re.sub("(^.*?)-", "\\1", str(irange)))

    # create one downloading thread per chunk
    downloaders = [
        threading.Thread(
            target=downloadChunk,
            args=(idx, irange),
        )
        for idx,irange in enumerate(ranges)
        ]

    # start threads, let run in parallel, wait for all to finish
    for th in downloaders:
        th.start()
        #th.isAlive()
    #for th in downloaders:
        #th.join()
        #print(th.join)

    #print('done: got {} chunks, total {} bytes'.format(
    #    len(dataDict), sum( (
    ##        len(chunk) for chunk in list(dataDict.values())
     #   ) )
    #))

    #print("--- %s seconds ---" % str(time.time() - start_time))

#    if os.path.exists(fileName):
 #       os.remove(fileName)
     #reassemble file in correct order
    #with open(fileName, 'wb') as fh:
    #    for _idx,chunk in sorted(dataDict.items()):
    #        fh.write(chunk)
    #stream_chunk = 16 * 1024
    #with open(fileName, 'wb') as fp:
    #  while True:
    #      for _idx,chunk in sorted(dataDict.items()):
            #fh.write(chunk)
     #       chunking = chunk.read(stream_chunk)
      #      if not chunk:
       #         break
        #    fp.write(chunking)


   # print("Finished Writing file %s" % fileName)
    #print('file size {} bytes'.format(os.path.getsize(fileName)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(URL, splitBy=3)
```

Comment: Did you check the file with a hex editor? Most editor stop working properly when they encounter some special characters.

Comment: I already check it in Notepad++, everything okay, problem is my file only return 1/3, 2/3 filled with "NUL"

Comment: You need to only open the output file once and add a `threading.Lock` to control access to it. Before each thread writes a chunk to the file, it would first have to acquire the lock, save the file's current position with `tell()`, the `seek()` to the proper position for the chunk it has received, write the chunk to file, then finally restore the current position with `seek()` using the saved position, all before releasing the lock.

Comment: Thank you, your help clearly open my mind a little bit, I update version 2 of my code, please give me some advice, thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use three threads where your target function is `downloadChunk`, you open the file three times using `wb` which **overwrites** so you get 1/3 of the content. You also call seek for no apparent reason. If you wanted to append to a file you would open using `a` each time or just open the file once outside the functions.
You are trying to seek using an empty file and write so that is where the null bytes come from.

If you want to open a  file for reading and writing so you can seek with line buffering:

```
 with open("whatever.file", "r+b",buffering=1) as f
```

Then use that file to write to, don't keep opening in the function and overwriting, the file must also exist.

Comment: As my knowledge about Cisco router, probably there is feature to limit bandwidth each interface. I experienced that download accelerator-like or video accelerator-like software really speed up my download speed compare with normal always 100KB/s, but with download accelerator I can reach 800KB/s.

Comment: Do you think this way is better than my way: http://pastebin.com/MLB6DYeG

I don't know if it is stream-able (buffer write like f.write(4028)) or not This code is not from me and it use a bunch of global variable so don't really understand the whole code, and also I doubt global variable is a bad design right ? For example I down two URL like http://1.txt and http://2.txt using that threading downloader, maybe they overwrite global variable of each other ?

Comment: There is rarely ever a use case for global, you can either pass in the variables as parameters or create a class with attributes.  When you have multiple processes writing to a file there is no guarantee of the order or the previous process is actually finished and the data is on the disk while another is reading/writing.

Comment: Thank you, I update version 2 of my code, please give me some advice, thank!